# cmake cannot find libsndfile

Tags: c++, cmake, centos, libsndfile

Cmake seems not to find the lib libsndfile. However, it installed on my machine.

```
find_library(sndfile REQUIRED)
```

And installed :

```
yum list installed | grep libsnd
libsndfile.x86_64                       1.0.25-11.el7            @base          
libsndfile-devel.x86_64                 1.0.25-11.el7            @base
```

The error :

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:65 (find_library):
   Could not find sndfile using the following names:
```

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_library(sndfile REQUIRED)

add_executable(untitled1 main.cpp)
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You added the CMakeLists.txt but did not post the next line of the error message. What does it say after ***Could not find sndfile using the following names:***

Comment: You forgot to specify **names** for you library in `find_library` call. The first parameter for [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) is a **variable** name, not a *library* name.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see now I understand the error message. I expect it's looking for a library named `libREQUIRED`

Comment: I would also ensure cmake has the correct values for `CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`, The suffix `.x86_64` seem unusual, linux distro usually have the `.a` extension

Comment: The yum is just the list of distro packages not the library name.

Comment: @drescherjm Oh! Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mean much if it is installed on your machine or not. CMake won't search all your computer for the library. The best thing you can do is to add the location of the installed library to your `PATH` environment variable.

Here's what CMake documentation says about `find_library()` `HINTS` and `PATHS` arguments:

> HINTS, PATHS
>
> Specify directories to search in addition to the default
> locations. The ENV var sub-option reads paths from a system
> environment variable.

CMake also provides another solution: set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
You can find more details about it [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html).

Comment: My call of find_library was wrong. If I defined : find_library(sndfile libsndfile), it works. Thanks